# Import "six.moves.urllib.parse" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I successfully installed "six" at the command prompt. Why does my "python" display "Import "six.moves.urllib.parse" could not be resolved from source" and there is a yellow wavy line.

```
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.16.0
```

[image]

Comment: Why not import urllib from the standard library, instead of using `six`?  `six` is only necessary if you are going to support Python2 as well as Python3.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. So I followed the "auth0" method. But I don't understand how to deal with it. use "from urllib import urlencode"?

Comment: don't know auth0, but in Python3 you can do `from urllib.parse import urlencode` - [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Comment: Python2's `urllib` and `urllib2` functions can be found in the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) package's subpackages in Python3.

Comment: Thank you very much, friend. There are no more yellow wavy lines. Thank you for your great help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

For python3